# Flutter (chat app): Push messages up when the keyboard is open

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a chat app in Flutter but I'm stuck with a bug.
My goal is to push messages up when the keyboard becomes visible. Everything works, but the message push (implemented as a scroll to the last message) starts with a slight delay. Instead of starting as soon as the keyboard starts to become visible, it only starts as soon as the chat becomes completely visible.

This is the code of the parent widget:

```
class ChatPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ConnectivityWrapper(
      child: ChatPageWidget(),
    );
  }
}


class ChatPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPageWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChatPageWidget> createState() => _ChatPageWidgetState();
}

class _ChatPageWidgetState extends State<ChatPageWidget> {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  late final KeyboardLifecycleEventHandler keyboardLifecycleEventHandler;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Listen to keyboard state changes to push up messages
    keyboardLifecycleEventHandler = KeyboardLifecycleEventHandler(
      onKeyboardVisibilityChanged: (bool keyboardVisible) {
        if (keyboardVisible) {
          // Schedule scrollToFitKeyboard to run after the next frame
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            scrollToFitKeyboard(keyboardVisible);
          });
        }
      },
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(keyboardLifecycleEventHandler);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(keyboardLifecycleEventHandler);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void scrollToFitKeyboard(bool keyboardVisible) {
    final double keyboardHeight = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .viewInsets
        .bottom;

    try {
      if (scrollController.hasClients && mounted) {
        scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.offset +
              (keyboardVisible ? keyboardHeight : -keyboardHeight),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String languageCode = Localizations
        .localeOf(context)
        .languageCode;
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
      builder: (BuildContext buildContext,
          AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
        context.read<ChatCubit>().getCredits();

        return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
          builder: (context, themeState) {
            return BlocBuilder<GeolocationCubit, GeolocationState>(
              builder: (geoLocContext, geolocationState) {
                final location = geolocationState.city;
                return BlocBuilder<ChatCubit, ChatState>(
                  builder: (context, chatState) {
                    //GET CHAT SESSION DATE
                    final formattedDate =
                    formatDate(chatState.messages, languageCode);
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                        scrollController.animateTo(
                        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.easeOut,
                      );
                    });

                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        FocusScope.of(buildContext).unfocus();
                      },
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                        child: Scaffold(
                          backgroundColor:
                          themeState.themeSchema
                              .bg()
                              .defaultColor,
                          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,

                          //Appbar
                          appBar: AppbarWidget(
                            themeState: themeState,
                            location: location,
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(buildContext).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (buildContext) =>
                                  const SettingsPage(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            context: buildContext,
                          ),

                          //Body
                          body: Stack(
                            children: [
                              SafeArea(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    //Chat body
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ChatBody(
                                        context: context,
                                        themeState: themeState,
                                        location: location,
                                        scrollController: scrollController,
                                        date: formattedDate,
                                        loading: chatState.loadingBubble,
                                        messages: chatState.messages.isNotEmpty
                                            ? [
                                          VestaMessage(
                                              text: LocaleKeys
                                                  .onboardingTwoChatOne.tr()),
                                          ...chatState.messages
                                        ]
                                            : [
                                          VestaMessage(
                                              text: LocaleKeys
                                                  .onboardingTwoChatOne.tr()),
                                          ...chatState.messages
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    //Chat input bar
                                    const SizedBox(height: 100)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child: ActionBar(
                                    themeState: themeState,
                                    scrollController: scrollController,
                                    loading: chatState.loadingBubble,
                                    credits: chatState.credits,
                                    location: location,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),

                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the child widget:

```
class ChatBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatBody({
    Key? key,
    required this.date,
    this.messages = const [],
    required this.scrollController,
    required this.loading,
    required this.themeState,
    required this.location,
    required this.context,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Message> messages;
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  final bool loading;
  final String date;
  final ThemeState themeState;
  final String location;
  final BuildContext context;

  @override
  State<ChatBody> createState() => ChatBodyState();
}

class ChatBodyState extends State<ChatBody> {
  // manage the visibility of the hidden text (change color)
  bool scroll = false;

  //manage the padding transition for the logo false if scrolling down (deactivate transition),
  //true if scrolling up (activate transition)
  bool scrollDelta = false;

  StreamSubscription<Position>? positionStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scroll = false;
    _getDeviceLocation();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    positionStream?.cancel();
  }

  final LocationSettings locationSettings = const LocationSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium,
    distanceFilter: 1000,
  );

  //Initialize get position stream functions (after proper permissions check)
  _getDeviceLocation() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (serviceEnabled) {
      permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      }
      if (permission != LocationPermission.deniedForever &&
          (permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse ||
              permission == LocationPermission.always)) {
        positionStream =
            Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
                .listen((Position? position) async {
          await context.read<GeolocationCubit>().updateLocation(position);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        setState(() {
          if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification &&
              scrollNotification.metrics.pixels < -10) {
            scrollDelta = scrollNotification.scrollDelta! > 0;
            scroll = true;
          } else {
            scroll = false;
          }
        });
        return true;
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: widget.scrollController,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        child: Container(
          padding: getChatBodyPadding(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(children: [
                // Top Chat body logo
                // Hidden top text (app-version; visible on scroll)

                Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: HiddenTopText(
                        scroll: scroll, theme: widget.themeState.themeSchema)),
                AnimatedPadding(
                  duration: scrollDelta
                      ? const Duration(milliseconds: 0)
                      : const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  padding: scroll
                      ? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)
                      : const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                  child: TopChatLogo(
                      scroll: scroll, themeState: widget.themeState),
                ),
              ]),

              // Chat session date text
              ChatSessionDate(
                  date: widget.date, theme: widget.themeState.themeSchema),
              // Generate list of messages
              ChatMessagesList(
                  location: widget.location,
                  loading: widget.loading,
                  messages: widget.messages,
                  scrollController: widget.scrollController,
                  themeState: widget.themeState),
              //Handle loading bubble message
              if (widget.loading)
                LoadingMessage(
                  key: ValueKey(const Uuid().v4()),
                  message: SpecialMessage.loading(),
                  theme: widget.themeState.themeSchema,
                ),
              //Handle start new chat message
              if (widget.messages.length > 1 && !widget.loading)
                CreateNewChat(
                  key: ValueKey(const Uuid().v4()),
                  message: SpecialMessage.newChat(),
                  themeState: widget.themeState,
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do to avoid the delay? Thank you

Comment: I think you're overthinking this.  Apparently, Scaffold and ListView (or other Scrollable) cooperate, such that when a keyboard is shown, the top-level scrollable is automatically scrolled to the same bottom position.  I might not be describing it accurately, but I've never had problems when I have a Scaffold with a body: that is scrollable.